# FileReader in Java and ready method

Tags: java, file-io

Ok, so I am reading a 40 mb file 1000 bytes at a time.
Each time I empty my buffer I check to make sure that the FileReader still has data to be read using the ready() method. However, it is returning false when there are bits that still haven't been read but the stream isn't ready. How would I circumvent this?

```
if( !fileInput.ready() )
            {

                    System.out.println(!fileInput.ready());
                      //empty the rest of the buffer into the output file
                     fileOutput.write( buffer.toString() );
                     fileOutput.flush();
                      doneProcessing = true;
            }
```

Comment: Why would you call ready when reading from a file? Just read until you get an EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing in this manner:

```
    Reader in = new FileReader(args[0]);
    Writer out = new FileWriter("output.doc");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
    String str;
    while((str=br.readLine())!=null){
        out.write(str);
        System.out.println(str.getBytes());
    }
    out.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where you are reading from fileInput and filling up buffer.
Try this instead

```
FileOutputStream out =  ...
InputStream in = .. 

int len = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 

while ((len = in.read(buffer)) >= 0)
{ 
    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}

in.close(); 
out.close();
```

Comment: technically, shouldn't "> 0" be ">= 0"? (if read() returns 0) The javadoc doesn't discuss this.

Comment: Ideally, it would be `!= -1`. Not that I could imagine a scenario where -2 would actually be used, but `-1` is very specifically the value used to denote end of file.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to read than using the ready() method. The trick is that the read method returns -1 when read fully.

```
char[] buf = new char[ 1024 ];

for( int count = reader.read( buf ); count != -1; count = reader.read( buf ) )
{
    output.write( buf, 0, count );
}
```

You can do a similar thing with InputStream if you are reading in binary. Just convert buf to byte[].